# Implementing a Notification System with MongoDB, Mongoose, and Express.js for Admin Dashboard

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am working on an admin dashboard with over 100,000 users. I am looking to implement a notification system using MongoDB, Mongoose, and Express.js. The goal is to have the option to send a message from the dashboard to either chosen users or all users, with the notification text being the same for all recipients.

I would like to avoid creating a separate notification object for each user and instead find an efficient way to handle this within the MongoDB, Mongoose, and Express.js stack.

Here are the key requirements:

The system should allow the admin to send the same notification text to selected users or all users.
I want to minimize the creation of individual notification objects for each user.
The notification system should be scalable for a large number of users (over 100,000).
I already have a MongoDB schema for notifications, but I am seeking guidance on the best approach to handle the notification logic and efficiently manage notifications for a large user base.

If anyone has experience or suggestions on how to structure the MongoDB schema, design the Express.js routes, and handle the notification logic effectively, I would greatly appreciate your insights.

```js
// My current schema looks like this:

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const notificationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  text: { type: String, required: true },
  users: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
  // Other relevant fields
});

const Notification = mongoose.model('Notification', notificationSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide better context on how you want your notifications to work for us to answer this question better. Do you want your notifications to be sent out to all users at the time of hitting send, or will it be sitting in their inboxes until the next time they login and see the notification? Are the notifications a one-time thing, or should the users be capable of re-reading older notifications, like with social media?

In general, the main criterion for making your decision is if your users need to have some control over their own notifications (options such as "Mark as Unread", seeing older notifications, categorising them, etc.)

If that is indeed what you want, then building a more user-centered schema for your notifications would make more sense:

```
const notificationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  text: { type: String, required: true },
  // Other fields relevant to notification information
});
const Notification = mongoose.model('Notification', notificationSchema);

const userFeedSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  notificationId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Notification'},
  // Other fields you might need such as isSeen, isClicked, or createdAt
  };
});
const UserFeed = mongoose.model('UserFeed', userFeedSchema);
```

With this approach, you're isolating the information a notification contains, and associating users to the notifications they need to be seeing/have seen.

Creating indexes with (notificationId) on `notificationSchema`, and (userId, notificationId) on `userFeedSchema` would be a good idea because of the number of users you have, and every notification would create many documents in your collection, and the queries would soon grow slow.